# How to create docker image with specific name

Tags: docker

From a Ubuntu shell I tried to create a now docker image with the following command:

```
sudo debootstrap trusty trusty_a > /dev/null
sudo tar -C trusty_a -c . | sudo docker import - trusty_a
docker run trusty_a cat /etc/lsb-release
```

I then got a 'docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?' error.

I tried the following:

```
sudo service docker start
```

and found:

```
start: Job is already running: docker
```

I am unsure then why I cant start the new image?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I hadn't added myself to the docker group so 'docker run ...' failed.

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ and add yourself to a docker group using this:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```